# SSIS - Assigning Variable from Results of Query Utilizing "For JSON" Clause

Tags: c#, arrays, t-sql, ssis

I have an Execute SQL Task in an SSIS package that I would like to use to assign its result set to a variable.  The SQL it executes is using a FOR JSON clause.  I am getting the error:

```
[Execute SQL Task] Error: An error occurred while assigning a value to variable "currentAppJSONData": "The type of the value (DBNull) being assigned to variable "User::currentAppJSONData" differs from the current variable type (String). Variables may not change type during execution. Variable types are strict, except for variables of type Object.".
```

but only when querying actual, live data.  For instance, I can get this task to work as I would like when I use the query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 CAST((SELECT 'hey' AS 'greeting' 
                   FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER) AS NVARCHAR) AS [json_data]
```

but not my actual query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 CAST( (
SELECT [FIRST]                                 AS [FirstName]
FROM   [person] [p]
       JOIN [application] [a]
         ON [p].[ID] = [a].[PERSON]
WHERE
(
 (p.[id] NOT IN (SELECT [record] FROM [tag] WHERE ([tag] IN ('test'))))
 AND a.id = '4CBE7065-4893-40F5-AD0B-9746C84A822A'
)
ORDER BY p.[last], p.[first]
FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS json_data
```

(the *actual* actual query is much larger than this, but I tried scaling it down to get it to look as much like the test query, that I have confirmed works, as possible.)

This would return something like:

```
{"FirstName":"Benjamin"}
```

I'm casting the results as NVARCHARs because I wasn't sure if SSIS was having trouble assigning the JSON object to a string, but it doesn't seem to have made a difference and I'm not sure if it matters.

Why can I assign the results of the first query to a string variable, but not the second query?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to have been related to casting it as NVARCHAR(MAX).  NVARCHAR works, though the value is truncated in the variable.  Not sure why it works like that or why it's truncated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the Connection Type you are using. Use the ADO.NET Connection Type:

[SQL Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnRmG.png)

And reformat your query to look like this:

declare @JsonText as nvarchar(max)

set @JsonText  = (
SELECT ...
  FROM ...
for JSON PATH
  )

select @JsonText

Finally, map the result to a User String variable like this:

[Variable Mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbJ3w.png)